# div rollover position problem in Firefox only,...weird

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, positioning

I'm completely stumped as to why this roll-over content is displaying incorrectly in FireFox only.

I have a page full of product thumbs. When the user mouses over the product thumb some info text fades in. All standard stuff and I'm using jQuery to do this. This works fine in Safari and Chrome but in Firefox the info that fades in (anchor tag with class of .tooltip) shows up in the wrong place.

If i go into the style-sheet and set this tooltip content from display:none to display:block, it will then appear correctly in Firefox.

http://www.tomcarden.net/birdy2/rollover-ts-tomcarden.net.html

i don't see how the Javascript could be moving the divs?

I'd be so grateful for any help on this!, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please provide the relevant code and html in your question so we don't have to go searching for it on your site.

This is the HTML you have now:

```
<div id="product-11" class="product grid f-cell"> 
    <a href="/product/k-mock-prod-11" title="View k mock prod #11" class="product-a"> 
        <img class="products-img-thumb" src="img/prod-11_thumb.jpg" alt="Image of k mock prod #11" />
</a> 

    <a href="/product/k-mock-prod-11"  class="tooltip"> 
        <span class="products-page-text"> 
        K mock prod #11
        <p>Lorem ipsum dollor etc. 
        <br/>Size: 10.75"w x 9.25"d x 4.75"h</p> 
        </span> 
    </a> 
</div>
```

The JavaScript is basically irrelevant here.

The problem, as far as I can tell, has to do with the way you're positioning your `.tooltip` anchor inside your `.product` item. Instead of doing it the way you have it now, add this to your `.product` or `.grid` or `.f-cell` class (I'm unsure which you're primarily using for your product divs):

```
position:relative;
```

Then you should *remove* the margin declarations in your `.tooltip` class and add this:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
```

Let me know if that works.